# How to merge 4 different keys and values arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

It seems to be a common question but I couldn't find any help...

I need to merge 4 arrays with different keys and values. So there are my 4 different arrays :

```
array(7) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "32"
  ["title"]=>
  string(7) "Blettes"
  ["product_type_id"]=>
  string(2) "43"
  ["quantity"]=>
  string(4) "1.00"
  ["price"]=>
  string(4) "2.80"
  ["created_at"]=>
  string(19) "2011-09-03 11:31:35"
  ["proposition_vente"]=>
  string(1) "4"
}

array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "32"
  ["achat"]=>
  string(2) "47"
  ["total_price"]=>
  string(18) "131.59999999999994"
  ["total_vat"]=>
  string(18) "6.8619999999999965"
}

array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "32"
  ["exposition"]=>
  string(2) "46"
}

array(3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "32"
  ["sale_queue_id"]=>
  string(3) "163"
  ["exposition"]=>
  string(2) "56"
}
```

Into this one:

```
array(7) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "32"
  ["title"]=>
  string(7) "Blettes"
  ["product_type_id"]=>
  string(2) "43"
  ["quantity"]=>
  string(4) "1.00"
  ["price"]=>
  string(4) "2.80"
  ["created_at"]=>
  string(19) "2011-09-03 11:31:35"
  ["proposition_vente"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["achat"]=>
  string(2) "47"
  ["total_price"]=>
  string(18) "131.5"
  ["total_vat"]=>
  string(18) "6.86"
  ["exposition"]=>
  string(2) "46"
  ["sale_queue_id"]=>
  string(3) "163"
  ["exposition"]=>
  string(2) "56"
}
```

I know I have to use the id to correctly merge them. I tried to use a combination of foreach() and array_merge() without success.

Any help is welcome :)

Comment: You have two *exposition* keys in your final array.

Comment: want to merge into single one? right?

Comment: ah yes I have to change some keys.. And yes I want to merge into single one

Comment: Can you show us what you've got so far?

Comment: I have four different functions, each return an array. Then I have: `foreach($totalProposition as $key => $value) {
        $result[$key] = array_merge($value, $totalAchat[$key], $uniqueSale2, $exposition2 );
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out with this:

```
foreach ($totalProposition as $key => $value) {
$test[$key]=array_merge($totalProposition[$key], $totalAchat[$key], $uniqueSale2[$key], $exposition2[$key]);    
}
```

Thank you for your help : )

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array_merge($arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4) should work.
```

You can try this too:

```
$result = array();
$source = array($arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4);

foreach ($source as $a) {
    $result = array_merge($result, $a);
}
```

Comment: the foreach + array_merge didn't work, also I have 4 main arrays with 20.000 different arrays inside. Like this `[0]=>{ ["id"]=>18 }`